# ¿Como agrupar un dataframe en base a la aplicación de una función para una columna determinada, con pandas y python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, agrupación

Para el siguiente trabajo muestro un df ordenado ascendente por el campo "GEOCODIGO", seguido aplico una función al campo "TOTAL_VIV", la cual va sumando cada registro hasta un limite <= 110, luego continua recorriendo el campo y va estableciendo las sumatorias, al final en una lista "col2", se muestran estos resultados.

La consulta y el apoyo que requiero es, obtener un nuevo DataFrame que muestre según el df original, que registros fueron los que se agruparon o sumaron según la función "suma_columna", dado que cada registro es único.

Lo que he podido lograr, es agrupar por otros campos, pero lo que realmente necesito es un df agrupado por las sumas de la función aplicada, y poder establecer que registro o filas se sumaron o agruparon.
Quizás me puedan brindar una posible solución al respecto. Muchas Gracias por sus aportes.!!

```
    ### Visualizamos el df

    Base_Mz.head()

       COD_MZA NRO_VIV DOMINIO COD_BAR  COD_PAR    GEOCODIGO         TOTAL_VIV
    0   Mz-001  V-012    2       1      N00x    080601001001N00x001     12
    1   Mz-002  V-005    2       1      N00x    080601001001N00x002     5
    2   Mz-003  V-018    2       1      N00x    080601001001N00x003     18
    3   Mz-004  V-017    2       1      N00x    080601001001N00x004     17
    4   Mz-005  V-023    2       1      N00x    080601001001N00x005     23

    ### Ordenamos el df ascendentemente por el campo "GEOCODIGO"
    ascend = Base_Mz.sort_values(["GEOCODIGO"])

        COD_MZA NRO_VIV DOMINIO COD_BAR COD_PAR    GEOCODIGO         TOTAL_VIV
    0   Mz-001  V-012      2       1      N00x  080601001001N00x001      12
    1   Mz-002  V-005      2       1      N00x  080601001001N00x002      5
    2   Mz-003  V-018      2       1      N00x  080601001001N00x003      18
    3   Mz-004  V-017      2       1      N00x  080601001001N00x004      17
    4   Mz-005  V-023      2       1      N00x  080601001001N00x005      23
    ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
    707 Mz-013  V-001      2       54     N00x  080601001054N00x013      1
    708 Mz-014  V-000      2       54     N00x  080601001054N00x014      0
    709 Mz-015  V-000      2       54     N00x  080601001054N00x015      0
    710 Mz-016  V-001      2       54     N00x  080601001054N00x016      1
    711 Mz-017  V-000      2       54     N00x  080601001054N00x017      0

    ### Definimos un función que se aplicará al campo "TOTAL_VIV"
    corpre = 0
    col = ascend["TOTAL_VIV"]
    col2 = []
    Li = 90
    Ls = 110

    def suma_columna(col, Ls):
        corpre = 0
        for i in col:
            if corpre+i <= Ls:
                corpre += i
            else:
                yield corpre
                corpre = i

    col2 = list(suma_columna(col, Ls))

    print(col2)

    ### out
[89, 95, 90, 97, 110, 104, 104, 105, 93, 98, 98, 100, 102, 92, 110, 71, 92, 105, 106, 110, 93, 97, 
95, 103, 108, 109, 109, 90, 103, 109, 101, 110, 106, 109, 102, 107, 94, 110, 109, 108, 102, 103, 106, 
102, 107, 104, 107]
```

Comment: Bienvenido @Victor Baquedano, lo que quieres segun entendi es crear un nuevo __df__ en el cual esten todos los registros que se hayan sumado, no?

Comment: así es @christian!! La función va recorriendo y sumando hasta que los registros sumados de la columna "TOTAL_VIV" sean <= 110. Aparte de conocer los resultados de la función, necesito saber que registros se agruparon en cada suma, con el propósito de clasificarlos para un siguiente proceso. Gracias por tu interés, realmente vengo iniciando en python y en R, por lo que todavía no he podido resolver con claridad este paso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bueno eso es facil te voy a dar un ejemplo sencillo para que lo puedas implementar en lo que quieres

primero haces las importaciones necesarias

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
```

luego necesitamos nuestros datos, en mi caso cree un arreglo para simular los datos

```
dt = ['hola','que','so']
sumaT=0
suma = 20 #esta variable es para el incremento
```

luego declaro un arreglo vacio para almacenar los datos del for

```
todos = []
for d in dt:
    sumaT+=suma 
    if sumaT<=100:
         todos.append(d)
    else: break
```

con estas lineas establecemos la estructura que tendra el excel

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'campos': todos,'total':suma})
```

si lo antterior lo dejamos asi el documento se creara por orden alfabetico,  asi que definimos su orden

```
df = df[['campos','total']]
```

ya solo nos queda nombrar el archivo y guardarlo

```
writer = ExcelWriter('ejemplo.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, 'stackoverflow help', index=False)
writer.save()
```

si esto te da un error es porque te falta la libreria de `openpyxl` lo instalas con el comando `pip install openpyxl` espero te sirva

Comment: Hola amigo @christian.!! Me ha servido de mucho tu respuesta. Solo quiero consultarte algo: Al aplicarlo a mis datos, el bucle logra retornar los elementos que cumplen la condicional, pero solo para el primer conjunto. ¿Como puedo lograr que siga iterando por toda la columna y me retorne en listas cada conjunto que cumpla con la condición de suma? por ejemplo: el primer grupo es [12, 5, 18, 17, 23, 14] cuya suma es 89 <= 110, el siguiente grupo es: [ 24,20,12,7,16,16] que suman 95<=110, y así sucesivamente en toda la columna. Esto me servirá para clasificar cada grupo. Gracias de antemano.!!

Comment: Osea lo que quieres es que de un conjunto de datos ```[[1,2...n], [1,2...n],...,[n...m]]``` se evalúe la condición para cada uno de los subconjuntos, no?

Comment: En resumen: Cuento con un df con 712 filas, lo ordeno ascendente por el campo "GEOCODIGO", el cual es único y cuenta con un numero de viviendas. Por lo que necesito agrupar estos "GEOCODICOS" en base a la suma de sus viviendas, que no exceda a 110. Este dato es del campo "TOTAL_VIV, por lo que el bucle debe ir recorriendo este campo, sumando cada registro hasta un limite <=110, cundo se cumple, sigue recorriendo el campo y sumado hasta volver a cumplir la condición, y así hasta el final. Por lo que necesito que la salida sea sub-listas: [ [12, 5, 18, 17, 23, 14],  [ 24,20,12,7,16,16], ....]

Comment: Bueno si es posible y te lo voy a dejar a ti para que encuentres la solución, si no puedes me avisas